# ¿Cómo mostrar una fecha guardada en MySql en un Datepicker con jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, jsp

Hola quisiera validar un combobox que tome el valor por medio de jquery para que me muestre los resultados en un datepicker. Estoy realizando una página web donde seleccionas un medico mediante un combobox, y lo que quiero es tomar ese valor y validar para que me muestre sus respectivos horarios en un datepicker.

Esta es la página para seleccionar los medicos.

```
<select id="lista2" name="lista2" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Pedro Altamiza</option> 
    <option value="2">Diana Suarez</option> 
</select>
```

Ya habia realizado una validacion que me muestra los datos en otra pagina en un combobox y extrae los valores de la base de datos. Lo realice mediante un servlet.

```
HttpSession sesion = request.getSession();

InterfaceHorario DaoHorario = null;
Medico medico = new Medico();

ArrayList<Medico> listamedico = null;
try {
    listamedico = (ArrayList<Medico>)sesion.getAttribute("listaMedicos");
}catch(Exception e) {

}
int idmedico = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("lista2"));

for (Medico objmedico : listamedico) {
    if (objmedico.getId() == idmedico) {
        medico = objmedico;
        break;
    }
}

DaoHorario = new MysqlHorario();       
ArrayList<Horario> listaHorario = DaoHorario.valiHorario(idmedico);       
sesion.setAttribute("listaHorario", listaHorario);    
sesion.setAttribute("Sesion", true);        
sesion.setAttribute("medico", medico);
response.sendRedirect("Horario.jsp");        
processRequest(request, response);
```

Y este es el codigo en la pagina de horarios hecha en jsp:

```
<select class="combohorarios" name="id_horario" 
    id="modelo" 
    class="form-control">
    <option value="-1">Horarios...</option>
    <%
        for(Horario horario : listahorario){
    %>
    <option value="<%=horario.getIdHorario()%>"> 
        <%=horario.getDia()%>  <%=horario.getHora()%> 
    </option>                                    
    <%
        }
    %>                                                            
</select>
```

La pregunta es si puedo hacer lo mismo pero en vez de imprimir los horarios en un combobox imprimirlos en un datepicker. Estaba pensando en implementar JSON para enviar los datos al servlet. No sé mucho de JQUERY. Ayudenme por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si se puede pero debes ingeneartelas un poco primero establecer un mindate  y un max date
http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#enableddisabled-dates

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
</script>
```

luego desabilita todas las fechas y luego habilitas las que tu necesitas

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker5').datetimepicker({
            defaultDate: "11/1/2013",
            disabledDates: [
                moment("12/25/2013"),
                new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 21),
                "11/22/2013 00:53"
            ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Pero me parece mas practico lo que haces, al fin y al cabo no necesitas que ellos busquen mas fechas, pues los usuarios necesitan es ver los horarios disponibles solamente, porque con el datetimepicker sera didatico pero solamente veran son horarios desabilitados y unos cuantos habilitados